# Weird IOexception for file.move

Tags: vb.net, file, ioexception

I writing a program that is supposed to copy and back up a file to two folders `Edited` and `Archived` respectively. I've checked my directories, they exist, and are entered correctly from what I can tell, I excluded them to keep this brief.

```
    If TxtDest.Text <> "" Then
        File.Copy(oFD.FileName, <Copy Destination>)
    End If
    File.Move(oFD.FileName, <Archive Destination>)

    MsgBox("Your file has been saved.", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "")
```

I'm successfully copying the file, but moving has been giving me issues. When it executes I get an IOException: "Cannot create a file when that file already exists." Does anyone have and idea as to why this is happening or know a way around the exception?

Thanks!

Comment: There error say's it all! Go to that path and there is a file already there that `exists`. I bet if you delete it and try it again it will work... To fix this issue, just check if the file exists, if not move the file...

Comment: You forgot File.Delete(<Archive Destination>).  You probably ought to think a bit about whether you *really* want to do that or you've got an "archive" organization bug.

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, the file path for the  are incomplete.

I had included the destination folders, but left out the file name. See below:

Was:
`"H:\AppDev\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\RawFixerTest1\Test Data for RawFixer\5820\Survey\FieldWrk\TDS\Archived\"`

Is:
`"H:\AppDev\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\RawFixerTest1\Test Data for RawFixer\5820\Survey\FieldWrk\TDS\Archived\" & fInfo.Name`

Where `finfo` is a File Info object.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the documentation on the [File.Copy method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.copy(v=vs.110).aspx).

`Copy(String, String)`  Copies an existing file to a new file. Overwriting a file of the same name is **not** allowed.

`Copy(String, String, Boolean)` Copies an existing file to a new file. Overwriting a file of the same name is allowed.

So if a file already exists in that location you need to use the second overload specifying True for the last argument to force it to be overwritten